# No results with C# web scraping

Tags: c#, html, .net, web-scraping

I'm a beginner and I want to try to do some web scraping with C#, but with this code, it does not return any results, even though it should return a full list of items.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetHtmlAsync();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static async void GetHtmlAsync()
    {
        var url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=playstation+5&_sacat=0";

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

        var ProductList = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("ul").Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("ListViewInner")).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Your `Main` method isn't awaiting the asynchronous call to `GetHtmlAsync`, so is exiting the program before it does anything. You need to make your `Main` method `async` too and await the call to `GetHtmlAsync`.

Comment: Do not ignore compiler warnings. Compiler warnings mean “this code will compile but will not do what you think it will” and that's exactly what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `async` in C# you need to be async all the way down (and up).

So, to call the `async void GetHtmlAsync()` method, your caller needs to be async.

For a method to be async, it can't return `void`, but instead we return a `Task`. Tasks basically represent the "potential to return a value" and can be handed around irrespective of whether the potential has been reached, so you can have a `Task<int>` that will get you a number *at some point*, if you wait for it to do so.

If you want to have the result before your read line, you also need to `await` the result.

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await GetHtmlAsync();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

## Full Example

I don't know which implementation of `HtmLDocument` you are using, so there is one using statement that needs to be replaced below (`using SOURCE.OF.HTMLDOCUMENT;`).

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SOURCE.OF.HTMLDOCUMENT;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await GetHtmlAsync();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task GetHtmlAsync()
        {
            var url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=playstation+5&_sacat=0";

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

            var ProductList = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("ul").Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("ListViewInner")).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(ProductList.Count);
        }
    }
}
```